# fixed span sidebar in bootstrap 2.3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I work with Bootstrap 2.3.1! now I have this code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to `fixed` `span2` for put `fixed` sidebar when browser scrolled. How to work Bootstrap for fixed span?!

NOTE: I need to have normal and responsive view layout also.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#affix

Answer (score 0):

If you check bootstrap then there is present **affix** class for position fixed.

IN bootstrap.css file

```
.affix {  position: fixed;}
```